# Manage your data from left to right

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a project that consists of retrieving commands and displaying them on a screen.

The problem is that when the commands appear they automatically go down one by one to the footer

I would like to have them start on the left and then continue on the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="TH">
            <br><br>
                    <ul class='list-column'>
                        <li>
                        <div class="NUMCOMMANDE">
                            <?php
                            $dsn="";
                            $user="";
                            $password="";
                            $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);

                            //REQUETES
                            $sql = <<<EOF
                            SELECT enc_id, enc_cmd_num, enc_paye, enc_prepared, enc_ext_ref, enc_heure_fab_deb, enc_heure_fab_fin, Client.cli_civilite,Client.cli_nom, Client.cli_prenom FROM Client RIGHT JOIN encaissement ON Client.cli_id = encaissement.enc_client WHERE enc_etat<>4 AND enc_date= '20221229' AND ((DATEDIFF(n,enc_heure_fab_fin, getDate()) < 3 AND enc_prepared <> 0) OR enc_prepared = 0) AND enc_emporte <> 1 ORDER BY encaissement.enc_heure_fab_deb ASC
                    EOF;
                            
                            $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
       
                            while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)){ 
                            echo "<span class='cmdnum'>".$resultrow["enc_cmd_num"]."</span>" ; }
                            ?>

                        </li>

                        <?php
                        $sql = <<<EOF
                        SELECT enc_id, enc_cmd_num, enc_paye, enc_prepared, enc_ext_ref, enc_heure_fab_deb, enc_heure_fab_fin, Client.cli_civilite,Client.cli_nom, Client.cli_prenom FROM Client RIGHT JOIN encaissement ON Client.cli_id = encaissement.enc_client WHERE enc_etat<>4 AND enc_date= '20221229' AND ((DATEDIFF(n,enc_heure_fab_fin, getDate()) < 3 AND enc_prepared <> 0) OR enc_prepared = 0) AND enc_emporte <> 1 ORDER BY encaissement.enc_heure_fab_deb ASC
                    EOF;

                        $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
 
                        if( $results )
                        {
                            while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results))
                            {
                                switch($resultrow['enc_prepared'])
                                {
                                    case 0:
                                        echo"<p class='ENCOURS'>EN PREPARATION<p/>\r \n";
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        echo "<p class='PRETE'>COMMANDE PRÊTE<p/>\r\n";
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ?>
```

[image]

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Can you post [mcve]?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I suggest learning about CSS Grid

Comment: But is that with css grid the commands that are not located outside the block will be automatically on the right?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are wrapping the database content in a <p> paragraph element - this is a "block level" element, so will naturally break content into separate blocks.

Try replacing your <p> and <p/> (which is incorrect btw as the slash should lead!), with **<span>** and **</span>** respectively.

Semantically, this might not be quite right but it might solve the problem. You may be better using @florin-matei's solution below with an unordered list along with CSS for a more semantic output.

Comment: @Peter Ryan I changed what you said, but nothing is displayed now

Comment: Try **View Source**  in your browser to see what it's doing.

Comment: @PeterRyan I reworked my code and this is what happens.
The numbers don't follow the commands but the commands line up 

The example is updated

Comment: I've had a more thorough look at your code (I did kind of skim it first time around!) and just to confirm what you are doing; you are outputting a <table> with one row and two columns. The first column outputs the **enc_cmd_num** column from an SQL query, and the second column outputs a static string, either "EN PREPARATION" or "COMMANDE PRÊTE" depending on the **enc_prepared** column. Is that what you __want__ your code to do?

Comment: ..and following up quickly, you appear to be running the same SQL query twice, which is a bad sign! You might be better thinking about what output you want (remember semantics), and then build code to do that.

Comment: @Pierre Ryan I removed the painting, I don't want it to appear as a painting anymore.

I only want the order numbers to be next to their preparation status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not *entirely* clear what you want to achieve, but I've refactored your code a bit and this might be a better starting place:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <?php
    $dsn="";
    $user="";
    $password="";
    $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);

    //REQUETES
    $sql = <<<EOF
    SELECT enc_id, enc_cmd_num, enc_paye, enc_prepared, enc_ext_ref, enc_heure_fab_deb, enc_heure_fab_fin, Client.cli_civilite,Client.cli_nom, Client.cli_prenom FROM Client RIGHT JOIN encaissement ON Client.cli_id = encaissement.enc_client WHERE enc_etat<>4 AND enc_date= '20221229' AND ((DATEDIFF(n,enc_heure_fab_fin, getDate()) < 3 AND enc_prepared <> 0) OR enc_prepared = 0) AND enc_emporte <> 1 ORDER BY encaissement.enc_heure_fab_deb ASC
EOF;
    $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

    if ($results) {
      while ($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<div class='NUMCOMMANDE'>";
        echo "<span class='cmdnum'>".$resultrow["enc_cmd_num"]."</span>" ;
                                
        switch($resultrow['enc_prepared']) {
          case 0:
            echo"<span class='ENCOURS'>EN PREPARATION</span>\r\n";
            break;
          case 1:
            echo "<span class='PRETE'>COMMANDE PRÊTE</span>\r\n";
            break;
          }
          echo '</div>';
        }
      }
      ?>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I note that your SQL statement joins to a **Client** table that is otherwise not used, so I assume you are doing something else with all this?

It *may* be appropriate to use a `<table>` if you are outputting tabular data. I'd personally avoid using `<center>` and instead use semantic markup with some CSS to visually center the content... but again, it depends what you need this for I guess?!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<ul class='list-column'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

and in css (or SCSS):

```
.list-column {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 70px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem is that the data comes from a database and not from the text and it messes up everything